# How do multiple racial power replacement feats interact in D&D4e?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, powers

If a character has two feats which both replace their racial power with another power, which one takes effect? For example, the Wizard's Wrath feat (*Dragon 381*) states:

> You ignore bloodied enemies’ fire resistance and fire immunity. In addition, you replace *infernal wrath* with *wizard’s wrath*.

and the Warlock's Wrath feat (*Dragon 381*) states:

> You use d8s for your Warlock's Curse damage. In addition, you replace *infernal wrath* with *warlock's wrath*.

If a given character has both feats, which power ends up replacing their *infernal wrath* power?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first feat you'd taken would be the only one to function, as when you'd take the second, you no longer have Infernal Wrath to replace.

Few of the feats that alter or replace/remove your racial abilities will have the racial ability as a requirement, which is an oversight, as you can take them but they do nothing.
Many feats, especially when multiclassing or certain Hybrids, have legal feat options that don't actually work because a feature or power is missing.

But the bottom line: If you don't have the thing, you can't trade it out.